# Security Scan returning an empty report

Tags: security-scan-tool

I'm running 1.9.3.9 and have successfully configured Magento Security Scan. The scan runs and reports no problems, but no report details are available. The "View Report" page on magento.com is empty (except for the page header) The PDF version of the report is empty. The site is behind a WAF.

This isn't correct behavior for a "no-problems" report, is it?

Comment: Mine is also behind a WAF and I am getting an empty result.